# Python pyramid i18n and pytest

Tags: python, internationalization, pytest, pyramid

I followed [pyramid i18n](https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/i18n.html#adding-a-translation-directory) to add translations into my application under the `locale` which works fine but `pytest` is not happy at all - I get errors like this

```
    def _isdir(self, path):
>       raise NotImplementedError(
            "Can't perform this operation for unregistered loader type"
        )
E       pyramid.exceptions.ConfigurationExecutionError: <class 'NotImplementedError'>: Can't perform this operation for unregistered loader
```

The `app/__init__.py` adds translations with `config.add_translation_dirs('app:locale/')`

`pytest.ini`

```
[pytest]
testpaths = tests
python_files = *.py
addopts = -p no:warning
```

The structure is

```
app/
tests/
setup.py
pytest.ini
...
```

Thank you,

PS: I found the same issue if I add the deform translations

Comment: It looks like you did not import `NotImplementedError` in your test setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you aren't invoking `config.begin()` and `config.end()` correctly around your tests such that the threadlocals are active. It completely depends on how your tests look what this actually means though. Pyramid's i18n system relies on the threadlocals being pushed properly for the duration of the test.